# Cpanel php version in terminal is different from php version in MultiPHP Manager

Tags: php, cpanel, whm

I am using laravel 8 and get error when I  install dependencies  via composer . when I checked the version of PHP from terminal of Cpanel  it says the version is 7.1 as following image
[terminal php version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPQKe.jpg)

but when I check the version from  Cpanel MultiPHP Manager it says it's  8.0 as following image

[Cpanel MultiPHP Manager version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ4i1.jpg)

how I can fix this issue? and upgrade the Cpanel PHP version to 8.0

Comment: Is `[talabata@cloudvpsserver ~]` the directory your website is hosted in? If not, what result do you get if you change directory and run `php -v` there?

Comment: yes its inside public_html of the account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enabled enabled php 8 for the specific website. If you want it for whole server and go to Multi Php manager and change the System PHP Version to php 8.

Now check php version with php -v , it will show you php 8